Adding results to map using QGIS Script
I'm trying to get the results of a native QGIS processing tool and add an extra point to it but the results don't appear in the map.
What is missing here?
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsFeature,
                       QgsPointXY,
                       QgsProcessing,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingOutputNumber,
                       QgsProcessingParameterDistance,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination,
                       QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination)
from qgis import processing


class Gera_Pontos(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    """
    Gera pontos ao longo da linha em espaçamentos iguais (exceto último ponto, que terá espaçamento reduzido)
    """
    
    
    #variáveis gerais
    lineInputName = 'INPUT'
    stepInputName = 'PASSO'
        
    pointsOutputName = 'OUTPUT'
    countOutputName = 'NUMBEROFFEATURES'

    #não mexer 
    def tr(self, string):
        """
        Não mexer
        Returns a translatable string with the self.tr() function.
        """
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    #retornar uma nova instância desta classe 
    def createInstance(self):
        # Must return a new copy of your algorithm.
        return Gera_Pontos()

    #definir um nome único para o seu script, sem espaços ou caracteres especiais
    def name(self):
        """
        Returns the unique algorithm name.
        """
        return 'geraPontos'

    #definir uma descrição para o seu script 
    def displayName(self):
        """
        Returns the translated algorithm name.
        """
        return self.tr('Gera pontos igualmente espaçados sobre a diretriz')


    #definir uma descrição de grupo para o seu código (onde ele ficará agrupado)
    def group(self):
        """
        Returns the name of the group this algorithm belongs to.
        """
        return self.tr('Classe de Locacao')


    #identificação única do grupo deste script (sem espaços e sem caracteres especiais)
    def groupId(self):
        """
        Returns the unique ID of the group this algorithm belongs
        to.
        """
        return 'classeLocacao'

    #Texto de ajuda
    def shortHelpString(self):
        """
        Returns a localised short help string for the algorithm.
        """
        return self.tr('Cria pontos para algoritmo de classe de locação')


    #definir parâmetros e outras coisas importantes
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        """
        Here we define the inputs and outputs of the algorithm.
        """
        
        
        # Input de linhas
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.lineInputName,
                self.tr('Diretriz de Input (linha única)'),
                types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]
            )
        )
        
        
        
        #Input de passo, distância
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterDistance(
                self.stepInputName,
                self.tr('Passo (distância entre pontos)'),
                defaultValue = 5.0,
                # Make distance units match the INPUT layer units:
                parentParameterName=self.lineInputName
            )
        )
        
        # Output de pontos
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination(
                self.pointsOutputName,
                self.tr('Novos pontos gerados'),
            )
        )
        
        
        # output de número de pontos gerados 
        self.addOutput(
            QgsProcessingOutputNumber(
                self.countOutputName,
                self.tr('Quantidade de pontos gerados')
            )
        )


    #script propriamente dito   
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        Here is where the processing itself takes place.
        """
        feedback.pushCommandInfo('Iniciando Código')
        
        
        #lendo tabela de linhas e conferindo se está ok (tem que ter apenas uma linha)
        linhasTable = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.lineInputName, context)
        lineCount = linhasTable.featureCount()
        
        if (lineCount != 1):
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.tr("É esperado que a layer de entrada contenha apenas uma linha"))

            
        #input de passo
        step = self.parameterAsDouble(parameters, self.stepInputName, context)
        
        
        
        #pegando último ponto da linha, pois o processamento padrão não retorna o último ponto 
        lines = linhasTable.getFeatures()
        lineFeature = list(lines)[-1]       
        lineGeometry = lineFeature.geometry()
        
        lineLength = lineGeometry.length() #comprimento da linha
        lastPoint = lineGeometry.vertexAt(-1) #último ponto da linha
           
        
        if feedback.isCanceled(): #verifica se usuário cancelou processamento
            return {} #retorna um dicionário vazio (diferente de resultado nulo)
        
        
         
        
        pointsResult = processing.run(
            "native:pointsalonglines", 
            {
                'INPUT': parameters[self.lineInputName],
                'DISTANCE':5,
                'START_OFFSET':0,
                'END_OFFSET':0,
                'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
            }, 
            is_child_algorithm=True, 
            context = context, 
            feedback = feedback
        )
        
        
        if feedback.isCanceled(): #verifica se usuário cancelou processamento
            return {} #retorna um dicionário vazio (diferente de resultado nulo)
        
      
        
        
        #pegando a nova tabela de pontos e vendo seus fields
        pointsLayer = context.getMapLayer(pointsResult['OUTPUT'])
        fieldsToDelete = [i for (i,field) in enumerate(pointsLayer.fields()) if field != 'distance'] #pegando todos os atributos da tabela que não sejam 'distance'
        
        pointsLayer.deleteAttributes(fieldsToDelete)
        feedback.pushCommandInfo(str(pointsLayer.fields()))

 
        #criando ponto para inserção
        pointFeature = QgsFeature()
        pointFeature.setGeometry(lastPoint)
        pointFeature.setAttributes([lineLength])        
        
        pointsLayer.dataProvider().addFeature(pointFeature)
        

        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Return the results
        return {
            self.pointsOutputName: pointsResult['OUTPUT'],
            self.countOutputName: pointsLayer.featureCount()
        }


In general, if your custom algorithm is just a wrapper for several chained child algorithms, you can just pass your algorithm's output parameter as the 'OUTPUT' parameter of the final child algorithm in the pipeline and let the processing framework take care of writing/loading the output depending on what the user selected in the output parameter widget.
However in your case, this is slightly complicated because you wish to take a temporary output of the child algorithm and modify it before it is loaded.
Usually, if your algorithm creates a new layer from scratch, it should be a QgsFeatureSink e.g. something that you can properly bind to one of your algorithms QgsProcessingParameterDefinitions.
I think your best options here are either use a QgsFeatureSink, bound to a QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink parameter and add all the output features to it, or just hard code the output from the child algorithm to 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', (in which case you should declare it as an output of your algorithm), take the result layer from the context, modify it then add it to the context's layersToLoadOnCompletion; however the user will not have any output parameter options.
Option 1:
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsFeature,
                        QgsFeatureSink,
                        QgsFields,
                        QgsGeometry,
                        QgsProcessing,
                        QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                        QgsProcessingException,
                        QgsProcessingOutputNumber,
                        QgsProcessingParameterDistance,
                        QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                        QgsFeatureRequest,
                        QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)
from qgis import processing


class Gera_Pontos(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    """
    Gera pontos ao longo da linha em espaçamentos iguais (exceto último ponto, que terá espaçamento reduzido)
    """
    
    
    #variáveis gerais
    lineInputName = 'INPUT'
    stepInputName = 'PASSO'
        
    pointsOutputName = 'OUTPUT'
    countOutputName = 'NUMBEROFFEATURES'

    #não mexer 
    def tr(self, string):
        """
        Não mexer
        Returns a translatable string with the self.tr() function.
        """
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    #retornar uma nova instância desta classe 
    def createInstance(self):
        # Must return a new copy of your algorithm.
        return Gera_Pontos()

    #definir um nome único para o seu script, sem espaços ou caracteres especiais
    def name(self):
        """
        Returns the unique algorithm name.
        """
        return 'geraPontos'

    #definir uma descrição para o seu script 
    def displayName(self):
        """
        Returns the translated algorithm name.
        """
        return self.tr('Gera pontos igualmente espaçados sobre a diretriz')


    #definir uma descrição de grupo para o seu código (onde ele ficará agrupado)
    def group(self):
        """
        Returns the name of the group this algorithm belongs to.
        """
        return self.tr('Classe de Locacao')


    #identificação única do grupo deste script (sem espaços e sem caracteres especiais)
    def groupId(self):
        """
        Returns the unique ID of the group this algorithm belongs
        to.
        """
        return 'classeLocacao'

    #Texto de ajuda
    def shortHelpString(self):
        """
        Returns a localised short help string for the algorithm.
        """
        return self.tr('Cria pontos para algoritmo de classe de locação')


    #definir parâmetros e outras coisas importantes
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        """
        Here we define the inputs and outputs of the algorithm.
        """
        
        
        # Input de linhas
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.lineInputName,
                self.tr('Diretriz de Input (linha única)'),
                types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]
            )
        )
        
        #Input de passo, distância
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterDistance(
                self.stepInputName,
                self.tr('Passo (distância entre pontos)'),
                defaultValue = 5.0,
                # Make distance units match the INPUT layer units:
                parentParameterName=self.lineInputName
            )
        )
        
        # Output de pontos
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.pointsOutputName,
                self.tr('Novos pontos gerados'),
            )
        )
                
        # output de número de pontos gerados 
        self.addOutput(
            QgsProcessingOutputNumber(
                self.countOutputName,
                self.tr('Quantidade de pontos gerados')
            )
        )

    #script propriamente dito
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        Here is where the processing itself takes place.
        """
        feedback.pushCommandInfo('Iniciando Código')
                
        #lendo tabela de linhas e conferindo se está ok (tem que ter apenas uma linha)
        linhasTable = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.lineInputName, context)
        lineCount = linhasTable.featureCount()
        
        if (lineCount != 1):
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.tr("É esperado que a layer de entrada contenha apenas uma linha"))

        #input de passo
        dist = self.parameterAsDouble(parameters, self.stepInputName, context)
        
        #pegando último ponto da linha, pois o processamento padrão não retorna o último ponto 
        lineFeature = next(linhasTable.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(1)))
        lineGeometry = lineFeature.geometry()
        
        lineLength = lineGeometry.length() #comprimento da linha
        lineVertexCount = len(list(lineGeometry.vertices()))
        lastPoint = lineGeometry.vertexAt(lineVertexCount-1) #último ponto da linha (QgsPoint)
        lastPointGeom = QgsGeometry(lastPoint)
                   
        if feedback.isCanceled(): #verifica se usuário cancelou processamento
            return {} #retorna um dicionário vazio (diferente de resultado nulo)
        
        pointsResult = processing.run(
            "native:pointsalonglines", 
            {
                'INPUT': parameters[self.lineInputName],
                'DISTANCE':dist,
                'START_OFFSET':0,
                'END_OFFSET':0,
                'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
            }, 
            is_child_algorithm=True, 
            context = context, 
            feedback = feedback
        )
                
        if feedback.isCanceled(): #verifica se usuário cancelou processamento
            return {} #retorna um dicionário vazio (diferente de resultado nulo)
        
        #pegando a nova tabela de pontos e vendo seus fields
        pointsLayer = context.getMapLayer(pointsResult['OUTPUT'])
        distanceFieldIdx = pointsLayer.fields().lookupField('distance')
        distanceField = pointsLayer.fields()[distanceFieldIdx]
        flds = QgsFields()
        flds.append(distanceField)
        
        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.pointsOutputName, context,
                                               flds, pointsLayer.wkbType(), pointsLayer.sourceCrs())
                                               
        request = QgsFeatureRequest().setSubsetOfAttributes(['distance'], pointsLayer.fields())

        feats = []
        
        for ft in pointsLayer.getFeatures(request):
            pointFeature = QgsFeature(flds)
            pointFeature.setGeometry(ft.geometry())
            pointFeature.setAttributes([ft['distance']])
            feats.append(pointFeature)
        
        #criando ponto para inserção
        pointFeature = QgsFeature()
        pointFeature.setGeometry(lastPointGeom)
        pointFeature.setAttributes([lineLength])
        feats.append(pointFeature)
        
        sink.addFeatures(feats, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)
        
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Return the results
        return {
            self.pointsOutputName: dest_id,
            self.countOutputName: len(feats)
        }

Option 2:
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsFeature,
                        QgsFields,
                        QgsGeometry,
                        QgsProcessing,
                        QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                        QgsProcessingException,
                        QgsProcessingOutputNumber,
                        QgsProcessingParameterDistance,
                        QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                        QgsFeatureRequest,
                        QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer)
from qgis import processing


class Gera_Pontos(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    """
    Gera pontos ao longo da linha em espaçamentos iguais (exceto último ponto, que terá espaçamento reduzido)
    """
    
    
    #variáveis gerais
    lineInputName = 'INPUT'
    stepInputName = 'PASSO'
        
    pointsOutputName = 'OUTPUT'
    countOutputName = 'NUMBEROFFEATURES'

    #não mexer 
    def tr(self, string):
        """
        Não mexer
        Returns a translatable string with the self.tr() function.
        """
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    #retornar uma nova instância desta classe 
    def createInstance(self):
        # Must return a new copy of your algorithm.
        return Gera_Pontos()

    #definir um nome único para o seu script, sem espaços ou caracteres especiais
    def name(self):
        """
        Returns the unique algorithm name.
        """
        return 'geraPontos2'

    #definir uma descrição para o seu script 
    def displayName(self):
        """
        Returns the translated algorithm name.
        """
        return self.tr('Gera pontos 2')


    #definir uma descrição de grupo para o seu código (onde ele ficará agrupado)
    def group(self):
        """
        Returns the name of the group this algorithm belongs to.
        """
        return self.tr('Classe de Locacao')


    #identificação única do grupo deste script (sem espaços e sem caracteres especiais)
    def groupId(self):
        """
        Returns the unique ID of the group this algorithm belongs
        to.
        """
        return 'classeLocacao'

    #Texto de ajuda
    def shortHelpString(self):
        """
        Returns a localised short help string for the algorithm.
        """
        return self.tr('Cria pontos para algoritmo de classe de locação')


    #definir parâmetros e outras coisas importantes
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        """
        Here we define the inputs and outputs of the algorithm.
        """
        
        
        # Input de linhas
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.lineInputName,
                self.tr('Diretriz de Input (linha única)'),
                types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]
            )
        )
        
        #Input de passo, distância
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterDistance(
                self.stepInputName,
                self.tr('Passo (distância entre pontos)'),
                defaultValue = 5.0,
                # Make distance units match the INPUT layer units:
                parentParameterName=self.lineInputName
            )
        )
        
        # Output de pontos
        self.addOutput(
            QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer(
                self.pointsOutputName,
                self.tr('Novos pontos gerados'),
                type = QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint
            )
        )
                
        # output de número de pontos gerados 
        self.addOutput(
            QgsProcessingOutputNumber(
                self.countOutputName,
                self.tr('Quantidade de pontos gerados')
            )
        )

    #script propriamente dito
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        Here is where the processing itself takes place.
        """
        feedback.pushCommandInfo('Iniciando Código')
                
        #lendo tabela de linhas e conferindo se está ok (tem que ter apenas uma linha)
        linhasTable = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.lineInputName, context)
        lineCount = linhasTable.featureCount()
        
        if (lineCount != 1):
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.tr("É esperado que a layer de entrada contenha apenas uma linha"))

        #input de passo
        dist = self.parameterAsDouble(parameters, self.stepInputName, context)
        
        #pegando último ponto da linha, pois o processamento padrão não retorna o último ponto 
        lineFeature = next(linhasTable.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(1)))
        lineGeometry = lineFeature.geometry()
        
        lineLength = lineGeometry.length() #comprimento da linha
        lineVertexCount = len(list(lineGeometry.vertices()))
        lastPoint = lineGeometry.vertexAt(lineVertexCount-1) #último ponto da linha (QgsPoint)
        lastPointGeom = QgsGeometry(lastPoint)
                   
        if feedback.isCanceled(): #verifica se usuário cancelou processamento
            return {} #retorna um dicionário vazio (diferente de resultado nulo)
        
        pointsResult = processing.run(
            "native:pointsalonglines", 
            {
                'INPUT': parameters[self.lineInputName],
                'DISTANCE':dist,
                'START_OFFSET':0,
                'END_OFFSET':0,
                'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
            }, 
            is_child_algorithm=True, 
            context = context, 
            feedback = feedback
        )
                
        if feedback.isCanceled(): #verifica se usuário cancelou processamento
            return {} #retorna um dicionário vazio (diferente de resultado nulo)
        
        #pegando a nova tabela de pontos e vendo seus fields
        pointsLayer = context.getMapLayer(pointsResult['OUTPUT'])
        fieldsToDelete = [i for (i, field) in enumerate(pointsLayer.fields()) if field.name() != 'distance'] #pegando todos os atributos da tabela que não sejam 'distance'        
        pointsLayer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes(fieldsToDelete)
        pointsLayer.updateFields()
        feedback.pushCommandInfo(str(pointsLayer.fields()))
        
        #criando ponto para inserção
        pointFeature = QgsFeature()
        pointFeature.setGeometry(lastPointGeom)
        pointFeature.setAttributes([lineLength])
        
        pointsLayer.dataProvider().addFeature(pointFeature)
        
        details = context.LayerDetails('Novos pontos gerados', context.project(), 'Novos pontos gerados')
        context.addLayerToLoadOnCompletion(pointsLayer.id(), details)
        
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Return the results
        return {
            self.pointsOutputName: pointsLayer,
            self.countOutputName: pointsLayer.featureCount()
        }

